# How do I teleport all entities within a certain radius centered around me to their relative coordinates in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to do this and it can't get it to work. I want to teleport every entity(except for me) within a certain radius(2 blocks) around me to the Nether like some sort of banishment.

I have tried this already

`/execute as @s[tags & stuff] at @s in minecraft:the_nether run teleport @e[target specifications, radius data] ~ ~ ~`

You see it specifically needs to be executed as @s. But the command above just does nothing.

If I try

```
    /execute as @s[tags & stuff] at @s run teleport @e[target specifications, radius data] ~ ~ ~
```

It does something but just teleports all entities to me. I can also teleport all entities to the nether but as soon as I just add the radius specification it stops working.

Comment: Hi Von_Leipenstein, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
/execute in minecraft:the_nether run teleport @e[put all data for radius here] ~ ~ ~
```